# Issue running ASP.NET Core in RHEL 7

Tags: asp.net-core, rhel, rhel7

I have built and published an ASP.NET Core application within Visual Studio 2017 targeting ASP.NET Core 2.2.8 Runtime.  When I deploy (xcopy) to RedHat and try to run in Kestrel I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
```

This is what I have in my .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    <MicrosoftNETPlatformLibrary>Microsoft.NETCore.App</MicrosoftNETPlatformLibrary>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>                                                                            
    <Content Update="appsettings.json;web.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.2.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.2.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.2.8"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: You might use `dotnet new mvc` to create a vanilla project and then compare your current one.

Comment: I just was able to successfully deploy and run a Self-Contained build to RedHat via Kestrel.  It was A LOT of files to copy over.  It confirms that the issue lies with dependency resolution.  It runs locally on the Kestrel server.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered in the RedHat documentation that RedHat doesn't provide the ASP.NET Core 2.2 Hosting Bundle.  Instead, RedHat recommends executing a Self-Contained build and copying all of the files (about 400) to your application folder.  RedHat resolves this with 3.0 by including the Hosting Bundle in its .NET Core RPM.

> The ASP.NET Core Shared Framework is not available on RHEL. Deployed ASP.NET Core applications must include the ASP.NET Core packages.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/net_core/2.2/html/release_notes_for_rpms/known_issues